# Sizing and text wrap issue within <ul>

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, frontend

Edit: Resolved first part of the problem, still need to resolve second part.

Here is a demo of an [app](https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18733/) I am making. I am implementing a feature that allows subtasks to be added onto any one todo task and will show whenever you click on the tasks. However, if there is a task with a long description such as:

```
<li>veryveryverylongstringveryveryverylongstringveryveryverylongstringveryveryverylongstringveryveryverylongstringveryveryverylongstringveryveryverylongstringveryveryverylongstring</li>
```

The list will overflow and increase the width of the table (click on any of the tasks on fiddle to see what I am talking about). That is the first problem that I want to solve. I have tried using CSS to fix this such as word-wrap:break-word and other suggestions from other stackoverflow posts to no avail on the div element that contains the lists:

```
<div class="container" ng-show="thisTodo.showSubtask" style="background-color:red">
```

This is problem 1: How do I make sure that the list elements will wrap and keep the original size of the table?

The other problem I have is that

```
<li>
<label>
<input type="checkbox">
</label>
<input type="form-control">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
</li>
```

Will not fill up the entire width of the cell that it's in. I am not quite sure how to go about solving this one either.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried not using a table at all?

Comment: I don't see the issue occurring in your demo.

Answer (score 1):

**1st problem**:
Have you tried this?

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

[Give this a spin](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/sfbn5wmz/), perhaps you can learn some from it even if its not perfect.

**2nd problem**:
The td width on the last column is too wide, perhaps this might help?

```
.table td:last-child, .table td:first-child {
    width: 1px;
}
// or more specific (less hacky)
.table td:first-child {
    width: 30px;
}
.table td:last-child {
    width: 52px;
}
```

**3rd problem(for extra credit)**:
Too few/many columns within your table above/below the main content can cause unwanted behaviour. 3x TDs means you should also have 3x THs.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Adding a third column in the header got rid of some top border 1 vertical pixel error.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/rwe37y16/)

Comment: Actually, I realized there is nothing wrong with the way I implemented, the table was being resize because my test case was a long string of alphabets without spaces so it doesn't get recognized as words to break. Do you have any idea as to how to fix the second problem?

Comment: Updated my answer to help solve the second problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.li{
word-break: break-all;  
}
```

would also help breaking down your characters to adjust width.

Comment: This didn't seem to help, still getting the same results as before

Comment: see this: https://jsfiddle.net/ydwdrdmd/ I added the style to the list-unstyled class within the tableview

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set `word-wrap: break-word` and a `max-width` for the `<li>` which is containing that long text. And if you want to fill the width of the container, I recommend you to read the Grid System of Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. You could use a `<div class="row">` with 3 columns inside:

`<div class="col-md-3">{content}</div>`

`<div class="col-md-6">{content}</div>`

`<div class="col-md-3">{content}</div>`

More information here: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Tried this before, bootstrap scaffolding seems to not work inside table cells